# Nothing showing in app from JSON url with Swift 3 and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I have an app that is using Swift 3 and Alamofire. The data is connected to two `cell?.viewWithTag(2)` and `cell?.viewWithTag(1)` which is an image (from url) and text. So when I run the project nothing is showing in my App. I have tested the JSON with `print(readableJSON)` and the JSON is getting printed into the console. So I am a little confused really. My swift looks like this:

**SWIFT**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct postinput {
    let mainImage : UIImage!
    let name : String!

}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var postsinput = [postinput]()

    var mainURL = "https://www.example.api.com"

    typealias JSONstandard = [String : AnyObject]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        callAlamo(url: mainURL)
    }

    func callAlamo(url : String){
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)


        })

    }

    func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
        do {
            var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONstandard
        print(readableJSON)

            if let posts = readableJSON["posts"] as? [JSONstandard] {
                for post in posts { 
                    let title = post["title"] as! String
                    print(title)

                    if let imageUrl = post["image"] as? JSONstandard {
                        let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageUrl["url"] as! String)
                        let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)


                        let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)
                        postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: title))
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }


                }

            }

        }


        catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postsinput.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        // cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        mainImageView.image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        mainLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].name


        return cell!
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "posts" : [{
        "id": "000000",
        "url": "/content/interview2",
        "date": "2016-11-03 09:01:41",
        "modified": "2016-11-03 09:03:47",
        "title": "An interview",
        "image": "https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/oregood.jpeg",
        "summary": {
            "value": "<p>Latin text here</p>",
            "format": "filtered_html"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: you get jason but not show data in table view right?

Comment: Correct Mohit..

Comment: I didn't see "numberOfSectionsInTableView" method, where is it?

Comment: @Nikita Patskov. I am fairly new to swift so maybe I have missed that....

Comment: @rob There is no need to add `numberOfSectionsInTableView` if you have single section.

Comment: Check in `numberOfRowsInSection` your `postsinput.count` and that elements in `postsinput` really have image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JSON response `image` key contains `String` not `Dictionary` also you need to reload your `tableView` outside for loop not every time inside the loop, so try like this.

```
if let posts = readableJSON["posts"] as? [JSONstandard] {
    for post in posts {
        let title = post["title"] as! String            
        if let imageUrl = post["image"] as? String {
            let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageUrl as! String)
            let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)
            let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)
            postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: title))                
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Suggestion :** Instead of downloading image using `NSData(contentsOf:)` on main thread batter to use library like `SDWebImages` or you can create your own async image downloader.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not displaying your JSON in table cells. You crate a copied object called "mainImageView" and never assign it as actual imageView of table cell, instead try:

```
(cell?.viewWithTag(2) as? UIImageView).image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage
```

postsinput contains image strings or images?

EDIT:
so it would be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        // cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        //let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        //mainImageView.image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage
        (cell?.viewWithTag(2) as? UIImageView).image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        //let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        //mainLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].name
        (cell?.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel).text = postsinput[indexPath.row].name

        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: inside your     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}, instead of  let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView AND

        mainImageView.image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage
The same thing apply to your label

Comment: Thanks but did not solve the issue. But its solved now thanks Repoguy