# SWIFT 3 - take out html tags from string taken from JSON web url

Tags: html, ios, json, swift, swift3

I was wondering how can HTML tags be stripped out of JSON from a web url. Do I have to use `NSString` of something similar.

So I am looking to strip out the html tags that are in the summary value. I looked around abit and it says NSString can be used but I was not sure if that was something that could be implemented into Swift 3. Any Help would be appreciated.

**My code:**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct postinput {
    let mainImage : UIImage!
    let name : String!
    let author : String!
    let summary : String!

}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var postsinput = [postinput]()

    var mainURL = "https://www.example.com/api"

    typealias JSONstandard = [String : AnyObject]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        callAlamo(url: mainURL)
    }

    func callAlamo(url : String){
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)


        })

    }

    func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
        do {
            var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONstandard
            // print(readableJSON)

            if let posts = readableJSON["posts"] as? [JSONstandard] {
                for post in posts {
                    let title = post["title"] as! String

                    let author = post["author"] as! String

                    guard let dic = post["summary"] as? [String: Any], let summary = dic["value"] as? String else {
                        return
                    }


                    print(author)

                    if let imageUrl = post["image"] as? String {
                        let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageUrl )
                        let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)
                        let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)

                        postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: title, author: author, summary: summary))
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }


        }


        catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postsinput.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        // cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        mainImageView.image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        //(cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView).image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        mainLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].name

        mainLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:14)

        let autLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel

        autLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].author

        autLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)

        let sumLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel

        sumLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].summary

        sumLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)


        //(cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel).text = postsinput[indexPath.row].author

        return cell!
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the response you're trying to parse?

Comment: Its the JSON structure from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526761/json-structure-with-swift-and-alamofire/40526993?noredirect=1#comment68294873_40526993)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to Plain Text in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift)

Comment: @Palpatim, where would you put that extension code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this code for stripping html tags

From your previous question

```
guard let dic = post["summary"] as? [String: Any], let summary = dic["value"] as? String else {
    return
}
let str = summary.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(str)
```

**Edit**

I have checked it and it is working

```
let summary = "<p>Latin text here</p>"
let str = summary.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(str)
```

> Latin text here

Comment: No error and the html tags are still there.... I have done 'guard let dic = post["summary"] as? [String: Any], let summary = dic["value"] as? String else {
                        return
                        
                        let str = summary.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                        print(str)
                    }'

Comment: you don't need to put it in else condition

Comment: @rob Can you post the string which you are getting in summary ?

Comment: "summary": {
            "value": "<p>Latin text here</p>",
            "format": "filtered_html"
        }

Comment: @rob i have checked and updated answer and it is working for me.When you are printing this string `print(str)` what are you getting in console ?

Comment: In the console its printing fine but &nbsp; is in there.

Comment: @rob What is that string ? give me that string so i will check it

Comment: I have updated the code with the additional code for you to see.

Comment: @rob you are saying it is printing correctly in console but not working on your cell ?

Comment: @rob Then I have answers what is posted in your question.The string is correctly removing html tags, but you are not able to properly use it in you table view cell, for that you need to post another question, my job is done here.

Comment: What if it is like " <span><em><img src='images/icon3.png' alt=></em><a href='#/userProfile/MQ==/MQ=='>John Snow</a> recognized <a href='#/userProfile/NQ==/MQ=='> Arya Stark</a> for Owns what's given</span>"